# Safety of trying to login (preventing time-attack)

Tags: c#, .net, security, hash, authentication

I came across a security issue. Please have a look at the pseudocode below

```
public static bool TryLogin(string email, string password)
{
    if (UserExists(email)) // here is the problem
        return false;

    var hash = GetRealPasswordHash(email);
    var hash2 = GetHash(email, password);
    return SlowEquals(hash, hash2);
}
```

Some of you may already see the hole. An attacker may perform a time-attack over the network - detect how fast the answer is returned and based on that detect if there is a user in the database or not! Having known that, the attacker may now check various passwords for the user he already knows that exists!

A word of explanation if you don't see the problem or don't believe it to be a problem (this is for hashes, but analogical issue is here):

> Comparing the hashes in "length-constant" time ensures that an
> attacker cannot extract the hash of a password in an on-line system
> using a timing attack, then crack it off-line.
>
> The standard way to check if two sequences of bytes (strings) are the
> same is to compare the first byte, then the second, then the third,
> and so on. As soon as you find a byte that isn't the same for both
> strings, you know they are different and can return a negative
> response immediately. If you make it through both strings without
> finding any bytes that differ, you know the strings are the same and
> can return a positive result. This means that comparing two strings
> can take a different amount of time depending on how much of the
> strings match.
>
> For example, a standard comparison of the strings "xyzabc" and
> "abcxyz" would immediately see that the first character is different
> and wouldn't bother to check the rest of the string. On the other
> hand, when the strings "aaaaaaaaaaB" and "aaaaaaaaaaZ" are compared,
> the comparison algorithm scans through the block of "a" before it
> determins the strings are unequal.
>
> It might seem like it would be impossible to run a timing attack over
> a network. However, it has been done, and has been [shown to be
> practical](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/papers/ssl-timing.pdf).
>
> [Here you can see the article](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#normalhashing)

What should I do then, **when I detect that a user does not exist**? I definitely should perform some more calculations, but what is a good technique here? What do you guys use in such scenarios?

If this is of any significance, I am using C#.

Comment: Many systems already leak that there is a username taken through their "reset password" and similar portals. If you want to avoid the time attack anyway, you can make a dummy user and run through the motions until the last step where you compare a known to be different value as the last step. However timing attacks against a user base are usually better solved by instead stopping repeated attempts as logins as the existence of a login is only valuable if I can brute force the password.

Comment: But what if the attacker has many computers or/and he changes their IP? He might use zombie computers for this purpose as well.

Comment: That is why I said for a user, not for a source. Basically if a particular user name fails, remember that that user failed. Either increase the time between attempts or lock the user out eventually. That way knowledge of a user name has a smaller impact on your security.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is easy, you follow the same code path whether the user exists or not.

```
public static bool TryLogin(string email, string password)
{
    bool userExists = UserExists(email);

    var hash = GetRealPasswordHash(email);
    var hash2 = GetHash(email, password);
    return SlowEquals(hash, hash2) && userExists;
}
```

Now you will need to make sure `GetRealPasswordHash` takes the same amount of time for a valid email and a non valid email and returns a "fake" hash for the non valid email (the "dummy" user's password hash Guvante was referring to [in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493150/safety-of-trying-to-login-preventing-time-attack/30493540#comment49064296_30493150)).

This makes sure that `GetHash` and `SlowEquals` both still get called with valid data but you ignore their results due to `userExists` being false.

However I also agree with Guvante on his second point, any normal system will lock the user account after a number of invalid password attempts. This prevents brute force/dictionary attacks against a user's login. You only unlock the lock on the login until after a period of time has passed or the user calls in and verifies their identity.

Comment: there could be a scenario when locking wouldn't help. Let's say I've just bought a large base of emails and I'd like to know which is registered at some particular site. If login is vulnerable to timing attacks - it would take me only one try per email to check it. When I know this mail is registered at that site - I can use some social engeneering to make some profit out of it. So I think it's a valid question anyway.